# What to do when *nothing* will stop a mv command that did not finish

Tags: linux, command-line, ubuntu-server, kill, mv

[image: Screenshot of mv command refusing to stop]

See screenshot. As you can see, I've tried all the things that I've read about to use. Nothing can kill this dang mv command.

The last line with "mv: failed" has been there for 12+ hours, running my CPU at 100%, before I started using ^C and others. Same thing happened yesterday with a du command. Nothing could stop it, so I had to send a "Machine ACPI Shutdown" command via VirtualBox VM.

I'm on macOS, running Ubuntu Server via VirtualBox. Attempting to recover data by copying one external hard drive to another.

I also have Linux GNU Screen running.

Update #1:
[image: results of the top command]

I was able to create a new screen, and ran the top command to verify that the mv process ID is 1159. The fuse-ext2 command is the one taking all the CPU's resources.

Comment: I think you need a reboot of the OS.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I guess so :(

Comment: Or unplug the drives (since this is VB you can try detach them from the VM instead).

Comment: It's almost certain that at least one of the drives is problematic (dying, or less likely, bad USB bridge firmware). It's odd that fuse is involved though, when ext2 is native on Linux.

Comment: `This fuse module permits the user-level mount of ext2/3/4 file systems.` Ah, but meh (normally we do that with udisks2 + polkit or fstab entry with `user`).

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618).

Comment: How about you use `killall`

Comment: @TomYan I was following this article https://mattbryson55.medium.com/netgear-readynas-duo-dead-how-to-recover-your-data-5e828191651 which suggests the use of fuse-ext2. Anyhow - I ended up just detaching from the VM as you suggested.

Comment: Do you have the same drive model that has "funky block size" though? (Honestly I don't think it make any sense anyway. If the drive has a block size that is not supported by the kernel / block layer, I doubt that using a fuse driver instead would help.)

Comment: While you can try again with the kernel driver, you would probably bump into the same problem if you are trying to recover from a rescue back to the drive you rescued from, which is IMHO a silly / pointless move / attempt -- don't cling to dead drive. On the other hand, it could be some hiccups of the VB USB passthrough support as well.

Comment: I don't think I have the same drive model.  Ok, thanks for the additional tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fuse-ext2 command is used for mounting ext2/ext3/ext4 partitions or image files onto Linux kernels, according to this FreeBSD manual page: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=fuse-ext2&sektion=1&manpath=freebsd-release-ports

And it appears that fuse can be installed on macOS as well using homebrew according to this github repo: https://github.com/alperakcan/fuse-ext2

I would guess forcing an unmount may help you. Using the "umount -f" command for the external hard drives that you are using. This article seemed pretty helpful on similar step that you could take to force an unmount: https://www.systutorials.com/force-linux-unmount-filesystem-reporting-device-busy/

These man pages explain in depth some of the commands used in the forced unmount utilities mentioned in the article:

Method 1: using lsof: https://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof

Method 2: using fuser: https://linux.die.net/man/1/fuser

Hope that gets you on the right track! :)

P.S sorry for all the articles, I was researching while figuring out possible answers to your question.

Comment: Great to know that I may be able to use macOS. Thank you for all the research - it's very helpful and will help me do my own research in future!